# Xamarin Studio after update lost syntax highlighting scheme, can't import

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just updated my Xamarin Studio to 4.0.2 (build 18), and now all my custom syntax highlighting is gone!  When I tried to import my saved highlighting scheme, it silently failed.  I noticed that the old highlighting scheme is saved in an XML format (as was also the case with MonoDevelop), and the new highlighting schemes seem to be exported in a JSON format.

Is there a way I can convert and import my saved highlighting scheme without doing it all manually?

Comment: I have xamarin studio installed and I could not even type a quote `"`. Only typing a quote in a different application, copying that quote, and pasting it in Xamarin studio worked.... I have my doubts about Xamarin studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: If the exported file ends with `Style.jason` it will import, e.g. `MySyntaxHighlightingSchemeStyle.json`.

This is coming from Mike Kruger of MonoDevelop via IRC.  I tested it and it works perfectly.  Thanks Mike!

---

There is not yet an easy way to convert highlighting schemes from earlier versions of Xamarin Develop or MonoDevelop to the new Visual Studio-based scheme of Xamarin Develop 4.0.3.  There is also not yet a way to import schemes into Xamarin Develop that have been exported by Xamarin Develop (like from one machine to another).  Xamarin Develop can import Visual Studio-style XML-based schemes, but it only exports JSON-based schemes.

Mike Kruger of MonoDevelop mentions this in his blog:
http://mikemdblog.blogspot.hk/2013/02/upcoming-color-importer.html

Related:
[I've exported my highlighting scheme in Xamarin Studio. Now how do I import it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559866/ive-exported-my-highlighting-scheme-in-xamarin-studio-now-how-do-i-import-it)

Answer (score 1):

Just checked in IRC myself since I was having the same issue.

This is a breaking change with regards to themes with the latest release. You can import VS themes into XS now: http://studiostyl.es

Comment: Is there a Xamarin/Mono IRC channel?