# I've exported my highlighting scheme in Xamarin Studio. Now how do I import it?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

The lastest update of Xamarin Studio changed how syntax highlighting is stored and exported, apparently to make it compatible with Visual Studio, and as a result my customized scheme was lost.  I painstakingly reconfigured the scheme and exported it.  But now when I try to 'add' the scheme into Xamarin Studio on another computer, nothing happens.

How can I import the exported scheme onto another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exported file ends with `Style.json` it will import, e.g. `MySyntaxHighlightingSchemeStyle.json`.

This is coming from Mike Kruger of MonoDevelop via IRC.  I tested it and it works perfectly.  Thanks Mike!